# Is the Schwinger action principle important in renormalization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, variational-principle, action

Is the [Schwinger action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%27s_quantum_action_principle) important in [renormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization)?

I want to know if this principle could help us to see if a model is renormalizable of not. If you have any other comment or information about renormalization and quantum action principle of Schwinger, please tell me.

Comment: This downvote is not mine, but could you elaborate a bit how you came to think, that the Schwinger action principle could help to analyze if a theory is renormalizable? Maybe it is just me but I have difficulties to see the connection.

Answer (score 6):

It's been known since the beginning that the Schwinger action principle is fully equivalent to the Feynman path integral:

> W. K. Burton, Nuovo Cimento 1, 355 (1955).
>   K. Symanzik, Zeits. f. Naturfor. 9, 809 (1954).

So all the issues with divergences and renormalization that arise in the Feynman path integral formalism appear in the Schwinger action principle approach, too. They're really physical issues whose beef doesn't depend on the formulation we choose, and Schwinger's is just another "picture" to define quantum mechanical theories.