# Equivalence of Schwingers action principle and path integral formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, action

At the moment I'm working with Schwingers quantum action principle. For the harmonic oscillator I understood why this action principle is equivalent to the path integral formalism for quantum mechanics.

But why is it equivalent to the path integral formalism for relativistic fields? I can't find anything really usefull to answer this question.

Comment: See Lubos Motl's answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69716/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a path integral of some functional $\Omega[\varphi]$ called the expectation of $\Omega$:
$$ \int D\varphi\, e^{i \hbar^{-1} S[\varphi]} \, \Omega[\varphi] = \left<\Omega\right>. $$

Now consider a small variation of the dummy integration variable:
$$ \varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(x) + \delta\varphi(x). $$

How does the expectation value $\left<\Omega\right>$ change? Obviously, it does not, since it does not depend on $\varphi$. But we could calculate the variation of the path integral:

$$ 0 = \delta \left<\Omega\right> = \delta \int D\varphi\, e^{i \hbar^{-1} S[\varphi]} \, \Omega[\varphi] = \int D\varphi\, \left( i \, \hbar^{-1} \delta S \, \Omega \, e^{i \hbar^{-1} S[\varphi]} + \delta \Omega \, e^{i \hbar^{-1} S[\varphi]} \right) = \left< \delta \Omega + i \hbar^{-1} \, \Omega \, \delta S \right>. $$

This is precisely the so called quantum action principle:

$$ \left<\delta\Omega\right> = -i \hbar^{-1}  \, \left<\Omega\,\delta S\right>. $$

Note that this equation holds even if we let $\delta \varphi$ to depend on $\varphi$, the only requirement being that the path integral measure $D\varphi$ is invariant under $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi + \delta\varphi$. In case it is not, an additional term will appear, which is called the quantum anomaly.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer?  In what way is $\Omega$ connected to observables / Operators?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp the functional $\Omega$ in the path integral corresponds to evaluation of the mean value of the corresponding quantum operator $\hat{\Omega}$. The details of this correspondence aren't always straightforward and depend on the regularization of path integrals. You can look this up in almost any introduction to path integrals. The important thing is that all observable quantities are of this form.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on that, because I would expect observables to be a function of $\varphi(t)$, not a functional of $\varphi$.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp but any function of $\varphi(t)$ is a functional of $\varphi$! And we can ask questions like "what was the energy at time $t$", to which generalized observables are associated.

Comment: you mean in the sense that I can define something like $\Omega_t[\varphi] = \varphi(t)$ ? Then I got it.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp exactly